# Which is best approach to follow having all the objects at one place in xml file or creating each class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In POM, each class file is created for each page and placing the page objects in respective classes. What if we maintain all the objects in xml or json file. Which is the most efficient way ?
 Because the pom model forces calling each element for every single action. 
For example, in the below method:

```
public void clickOnElement(WebElement element) {
element.click();
}
```

How can we handle this dynamically if objects are placed in each class?

Answer (score 1):

A core principle in the page object model is that everything to do with a page is contained in the class for that page object. You shouldn't store locators, etc. outside of that class file.

Having said that, if you have some generic helper methods, e.g. `clickOnElement()`, etc. then you would store those in a `Utils` class and then call them from your page object.

Your page object would contain

```
private final By usernameLocator = By.id("username");
private final By passwordLocator = By.id("password");
private final By signInButtonLocator = By.id("signin");

...

public void login(string username, string password)
{
    Utils.findElement(usernameLocator).sendKeys(username);
    Utils.findElement(passwordLocator).sendKeys(password);
    Utils.clickElement(signInButtonLocator);
}
```

Your `Utils` class would contain helper methods like

```
public WebElement findElement(By locator)
{
    return driver.findElement(locator);
}

public void clickElement(By locator)
{
    findElement(locator).click();
}
```

Alternatively you could have each of your page objects inherit from a `BasePage` class that contains these helper methods. That would change `Utils.findElement()` to `findElement()`. Either way, it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSON Page Object Model. By injecting JQuery into the console, you can make the browser create a model object of the page for you

For reference:
http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-scriptless-page-object-design-pattern-part-1/